# How can I change the font of only specific words/ phrases in my Tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to analyse a sentence. Then depending on the mood/ tone of the sentence I choose a custom font and display it in the widget. The problem is I don't know how to change fonts of individual words/ sentences. I get the correct font name in the `desired_font` varaible in `FontFormatter` class. I only need to apply the font.
This is my current code

```
from wordToneRecog.font_apply import *
# Import the tkinter module
import tkinter
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


font_style = "C:\\Users\\JESUS\\Desktop\\Ethan\\auto work\\blog\\font\\styles\\RubikIso-Regular.ttf"
# font_style = 'styles\RubikIso-Regular.ttf'

# Creating the GUI window.
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Text Mood Font Changer")
#root.geometry("780x620")
root.state('zoomed')
win_width, win_height = (root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height())

def edit_output(text, widgetVar):
    widgetVar.configure(state = 'normal')
    widgetVar.insert("1.0", text)
    widgetVar.configure(state = 'disabled')

def copy_button(OutText: str):
    root.clipboard_clear()
    root.clipboard_append(OutText)
    root.update()

im = Image.open('pathto\\copy.png')
im = im.resize((30, 30))
ph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
available_fonts = {"superior": ('Black Ops One'), "old": ('Dancing Script'), "mystery": ('Sedgwick Ave Display'), "new": ('Ethnocentric Rg'), "lively": ('Pricedown Bl')}

class FontFormater():
    def __init__(self):
        self.corresponding_font = []
    def format_font(self, font_word_tuple,):
        for each_tuple in font_word_tuple:
            #print(available_fonts[each_tuple[1]] + ", " + each_tuple[0])
            # edit_output(each_tuple[0], widgetVar)
            self.corresponding_font.append((each_tuple[0], available_fonts[each_tuple[1]]))
        return self.corresponding_font
    def apply_font_to_text(self, widgetVar, font_word_tuple):
        widgetVar.configure(state = 'normal')
        for each_tuple in font_word_tuple:
            desired_font = available_fonts[each_tuple[1]]

            # I need to change my font here somehow

            self.FE = FontExtractor("In London's heart, a tale unfolds,\n A city of stories, legends of old.")
            self.FE.extract_font()
            poem = self.FE.write_ordered_words_in_full()
            print(each_tuple[0], desired_font)
        edit_output(widgetVar=widgetVar, text=poem)
        
        #     widgetVar.tag_configure(each_tuple[0], font= (available_fonts[each_tuple[1]], 20))
        # widgetVar.configure(state = 'disabled')
            

# Creating our text widget.
input_text = tkinter.Text(root, height=19, width=38)
output_text = tkinter.Text(root, height=16, width=35, font=('Black Ops One', 20))
copy_output_button = tkinter.Button(root,image=ph, command=lambda: copy_button(output_text.get("1.0", 'end-1c')))

# extractor = FontExtractor("In London's heart, a tale unfolds, A city of stories, legends of old.")
# fonts = extractor.extract_font()
# extractor.write_ordered_words_in_full()

ff = FontExtractor("In London's heart, a tale unfolds,\n A city of stories, legends of old.")
ff = ff.extract_font()
FontFormater().apply_font_to_text(output_text, ff)

#Font_tuple = ('Rubik Iso', 20, "bold")
#output_text.configure(font = Font_tuple)
input_text.configure(font = ('ariel', 20))
#edit_output(txt, output_text)

input_text.place(x=40, y=60)
output_text.place(x=(((win_width*1000)/20)*13), y=60)
copy_output_button.place(x=1280, y=20)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm currently using custom downloaded and installed fonts and I'm getting my correct font names in `desired_font` variable. I'm pretty sure I need to use some `.tag_add()` and `.tag_config()` but i have no idea about how to use it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

actually there is nothing "built-in" so in tkinter. You can try to do what you wantwith 2 labels like this :
Label1 -> normal label

Label2 -> bold label

And place each other closely

You can also use Frame from tkinter to group by those labels

Good luck with your program !

Comment: I had the idea in mind but, can it be made scrollable so that I can display large amount of text?

Comment: @EthanRodrigues : yes a frame can be scrollable ! This website explain it pretty clearly : https://coderslegacy.com/python/make-scrollable-frame-in-tkinter/

Answer (score 1):

Text widget have tags, you can 'create' and assign tags to index.

I use fonts that are installed on my machine

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font

class App():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        #set your fonts...
        self.font_14 = tkinter.font.Font( family = "Nakula", 
                                 size = 14)
        self.font_14_bold = tkinter.font.Font( family = "Andika", 
                                 size = 14,
                                 weight="bold")
                                 
        #create a text widget
        self.text_w = tk.Text(root)
        self.text_w.pack()
        
        #insert a dummy text  
        self.text_w.insert(tk.END, "My name is Python not Java")
        
        #Tags are objects having state, they don't need to be explicitly created
        self.text_w.tag_configure("tag_bold_txt", font=self.font_14_bold)
        self.text_w.tag_configure("tag_color_txt", font=self.font_14, foreground="coral1")
        
        #assign tag to a given index
        self.text_w.tag_add("tag_bold_txt", 1.11, 1.17) 
        self.text_w.tag_add("tag_color_txt", 1.22, 1.26) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Doesn't this only change the font of the mentioned indexes? I need to change specific words font. Maybe I can try finding the indexes of the word. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: usually you do some kind of search for word and get the indexes than you apply tags. for searching you can use your own regex expressions, the text widget has his own text.search() method. enjoy